# How to save and redirect mail with exim 4

Tags: linux, exim, exim4

I have working redirecting configuration for exim4 on my server with the help of tutorial. It works with virtual hosts, I followed the following [tutorial](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/140/Handling_mail_for_multiple_virtual_domains_with_exim4) - the last part

```
vdom_aliases:
  driver = redirect
  allow_defer
  allow_fail
  domains = dsearch;/etc/exim4/virtual
  data = ${expand:${lookup{$local_part}lsearch*@{/etc/exim4/virtual/$domain}}}
  retry_use_local_part
  pipe_transport   = address_pipe
  file_transport   = address_file
  no_more
```

What I need is to not only redirect the mails to the ones specified but also save them first locally.

Is there a way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use verb `unseen` in the routers. Usually first matched router process message and then routing is complete. But when matching router have `unseen` processing continues like message wasn't been matched before.

```
vdom_aliases: # redirect message
  driver = redirect
  domains = dsearch;/etc/exim4/virtual
  data = ${expand:${lookup{$local_part}lsearch*@{/etc/exim4/virtual/$domain}}}
  unseen      # keep routing

localdeliver: # do everything else
  driver = accept
. . . . . . . .
```

Comment: I tried but then I found this in my paniclog:
2014-08-20 16:13:57 Exim configuration error:
  localdeliver router:
  a transport is required for this router

Comment: Sure you have to white router completely, I've only give an idea.

Comment: Ah and couldn't you help me? I really don't get this stuff

Comment: You have to explain what exactly do you want

Comment: Ah, nothing more, thank you very much, I just added the unseen and Exim processed it somehow on its own.